# Probability of m crossings of 0 before time n of a Gaussian random walk

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, brownian-motion

Let $S_n = \sum_{n=1}^n X_n$ be a Gaussian random walk where $X_n$ are i.i.d random variables with distribution $\mathcal{N} (0,1)$. Could anyone show some hints and reference about how to compute the following probability?

Let $M(n)$ be the number of crossings of $0$ before time $n$, i.e., the largest integer $k$ such that there exists a strictly increasing finite sequence $a_1 < b_1 < a_2 < b_2 < \ldots < a_k < b_k$
of nonnegative integers smaller than or equal to $n$ with the properties $S_{a_i} < 0$ and $S_{b_i} > 0$ for every $i$. Then for any $m <n$, what is 
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( M(n) < m \right)?
$$

A good upper bound(e.g. exponentially small) of this probability also provides an answer.

Comment: Certainly not exponential: $P(M(n)=0)\sim 1/\sqrt{n}$